# Add arrows next to many polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geoprocessing

I have many polygons that present wind directional movement.

I use Arc-Map 10.3.1.

How can I add arrows next to each polygon, to show the wind direction in any polygon?

Comment: How do you use polygons to represent wind direction?

Comment: a point symbol at the centroid rotated to the wind direction

Comment: The polygons do not present wind direction, but they do present dust emissions sources. During the data collection, I documented azimuth movement of each dust storm. So, in this case, I want to show the dust  direction movement.

Answer (score 1):

If your polygon data have wind directions stored in the attribute table you could convert those polygons to points.  Symbolize those points with something that is arrow like, then in Layer Properties, Labels, Placement Properties, use the Rotate by Attribute.
Of course, this will put arrows inside the polygons, and you will need an advanced license to do the conversions from polygon to point.